# Reformat name/value pairs before form submit php

Tags: php, forms

I have a search form that I created using the following code:

```
    echo'<div class="header-img">
    <form method="get" class="cat-search" action="'.esc_url( home_url( '/search' ) ).'" role="search" >
        <select name="category">';
        foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
            echo'<option value="'.$category->slug.'">'.$category->name.'</option>';
        }
        echo'</select>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
        <input value="Search" type="submit" />
    </form>
</div>';
```

Currently, on submit, the url that's created looks something like this /?category=a&gender=male

How can I modify the url on submit so it comes up like this /?s=a+male

Comment: If you are going to use HTML, please just close the PHP tags and write it, it is more readable and easier to use.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean? Do you mean write it like this instead?

`<div class="header-img">
<form method="get" class="cat-search" action="<?php esc_url( home_url( '/search' ) ) ?>" role="search" >
    <select name="category">
    <?php foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
        echo'<option value="'.$category->slug.'">'.$category->name.'</option>';
    } ?>
    </select>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
    <input value="Search" type="submit" />
</form>`

Comment: Yes, yes and yes! The readability is improved massively.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip. I've always just written PHP that way. I'll try to start writing it like you suggested.

Comment: You need to use javascript/jquery to modify the action attribute on submit by preventing the form from submitting or dynamically fill a hidden form based on the values without form. Many ways to achieve this.

Comment: Ok, I will look this up to see how I can achieve this. Thanks!